# Pulling articles from specific category through Joomla! 3.0 Module

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

Here is the scenario, and let me start off saying any help would be a god-send, I have cloned the Article Category module inside Joomla! Basically changed all the articles_category to breed_articles (for my purpose). This worked fine, where I am stuck at is where in the module code can I define a specific category to pull articles from.

I know I can do this in the backend but I am working on a dynamic way to pull articles by categories and need to define the category in the module code. That being said, I will also need to pull the categoies by the slug not id.

Where I have been looking is the helper.php file in the module and I believe that I am on the right path there. I have tried replacing a few things and tracing the code but I am not very familiar with Joomla!

helper.php

```
$com_path = JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/';
require_once $com_path.'router.php';
require_once $com_path.'helpers/route.php';

JModelLegacy::addIncludePath($com_path . '/models', 'ContentModel');

abstract class modBreedArticlesHelper
{
public static function getList(&$params)
{
    // Get an instance of the generic articles model
    $articles = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

    // Set application parameters in model
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $appParams = $app->getParams();
    $articles->setState('params', $appParams);

    // Set the filters based on the module params
    $articles->setState('list.start', 0);
    $articles->setState('list.limit', (int) $params->get('count', 0));
    $articles->setState('filter.published', 1);

    // Access filter
    $access = !JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content')->get('show_noauth');
    $authorised = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id'));
    $articles->setState('filter.access', $access);

    // Prep for Normal or Dynamic Modes
    $mode = $params->get('mode', 'normal');
    switch ($mode)
    {
        case 'dynamic':
            $option = $app->input->get('option');
            $view = $app->input->get('view');
            if ($option === 'com_content') {
                switch($view)
                {
                    case 'category':
                        $catids = array($app->input->getInt('id'));
                        break;
                    case 'categories':
                        $catids = array($app->input->getInt('id'));
                        break;
                    case 'article':
                        if ($params->get('show_on_article_page', 1)) {
                            $article_id = $app->input->getInt('id');
                            $catid = $app->input->getInt('catid');

                            if (!$catid) {
                                // Get an instance of the generic article model
                                $article = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));

                                $article->setState('params', $appParams);
                                $article->setState('filter.published', 1);
                                $article->setState('article.id', (int) $article_id);
                                $item = $article->getItem();

                                $catids = array($item->catid);
                            }
                            else {
                                $catids = array($catid);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            // Return right away if show_on_article_page option is off
                            return;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'featured':
                    default:
                        // Return right away if not on the category or article views
                        return;
                }
            }
            else {
                // Return right away if not on a com_content page
                return;
            }

            break;

        case 'normal':
        default:
            $catids = $params->get('catid');
            $articles->setState('filter.category_id.include', (bool) $params->get('category_filtering_type', 1));
            break;
    }

    // Category filter
    if ($catids) {
        if ($params->get('show_child_category_articles', 0) && (int) $params->get('levels', 0) > 0) {
            // Get an instance of the generic categories model
            $categories = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Categories', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
            $categories->setState('params', $appParams);
            $levels = $params->get('levels', 1) ? $params->get('levels', 1) : 9999;
            $categories->setState('filter.get_children', $levels);
            $categories->setState('filter.published', 1);
            $categories->setState('filter.access', $access);
            $additional_catids = array();

            foreach($catids as $catid)
            {
                $categories->setState('filter.parentId', $catid);
                $recursive = true;
                $items = $categories->getItems($recursive);

                if ($items)
                {
                    foreach($items as $category)
                    {
                        $condition = (($category->level - $categories->getParent()->level) <= $levels);
                        if ($condition) {
                            $additional_catids[] = $category->id;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            $catids = array_unique(array_merge($catids, $additional_catids));
        }

        $articles->setState('filter.category_id', $catids);
    }

    // Ordering
    $articles->setState('list.ordering', $params->get('article_ordering', 'a.ordering'));
    $articles->setState('list.direction', $params->get('article_ordering_direction', 'ASC'));

    // New Parameters
    $articles->setState('filter.featured', $params->get('show_front', 'show'));
    $articles->setState('filter.author_id', $params->get('created_by', ""));
    $articles->setState('filter.author_id.include', $params->get('author_filtering_type', 1));
    $articles->setState('filter.author_alias', $params->get('created_by_alias', ""));
    $articles->setState('filter.author_alias.include', $params->get('author_alias_filtering_type', 1));
    $excluded_articles = $params->get('excluded_articles', '');

    if ($excluded_articles) {
        $excluded_articles = explode("\r\n", $excluded_articles);
        $articles->setState('filter.article_id', $excluded_articles);
        $articles->setState('filter.article_id.include', false); // Exclude
    }

    $date_filtering = $params->get('date_filtering', 'off');
    if ($date_filtering !== 'off') {
        $articles->setState('filter.date_filtering', $date_filtering);
        $articles->setState('filter.date_field', $params->get('date_field', 'a.created'));
        $articles->setState('filter.start_date_range', $params->get('start_date_range', '1000-01-01 00:00:00'));
        $articles->setState('filter.end_date_range', $params->get('end_date_range', '9999-12-31 23:59:59'));
        $articles->setState('filter.relative_date', $params->get('relative_date', 30));
    }

    // Filter by language
    $articles->setState('filter.language', $app->getLanguageFilter());

    $items = $articles->getItems();

    // Display options
    $show_date = $params->get('show_date', 0);
    $show_date_field = $params->get('show_date_field', 'created');
    $show_date_format = $params->get('show_date_format', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $show_category = $params->get('show_category', 0);
    $show_hits = $params->get('show_hits', 0);
    $show_author = $params->get('show_author', 0);
    $show_introtext = $params->get('show_introtext', 0);
    $introtext_limit = $params->get('introtext_limit', 100);

    // Find current Article ID if on an article page
    $option = $app->input->get('option');
    $view = $app->input->get('view');

    if ($option === 'com_content' && $view === 'article') {
        $active_article_id = $app->input->getInt('id');
    }
    else {
        $active_article_id = 0;
    }

    // Prepare data for display using display options
    foreach ($items as &$item)
    {
        $item->slug = $item->id.':'.$item->alias;
        $item->catslug = $item->catid ? $item->catid .':'.$item->category_alias : $item->catid;

        if ($access || in_array($item->access, $authorised))
        {
            // We know that user has the privilege to view the article
            $item->link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->slug, $item->catslug));
        }
        else
        {
            $app  = JFactory::getApplication();
            $menu = $app->getMenu();
            $menuitems = $menu->getItems('link', 'index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
            if (isset($menuitems[0]))
            {
                $Itemid = $menuitems[0]->id;
            }
            elseif ($app->input->getInt('Itemid') > 0)
            {
                // Use Itemid from requesting page only if there is no existing menu
                $Itemid = $app->input->getInt('Itemid');
            }

            $item->link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login&Itemid='.$Itemid);
        }

        // Used for styling the active article
        $item->active = $item->id == $active_article_id ? 'active' : '';

        $item->displayDate = '';
        if ($show_date) {
            $item->displayDate = JHTML::_('date', $item->$show_date_field, $show_date_format);
        }

        if ($item->catid) {
            $item->displayCategoryLink = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->catid));
            $item->displayCategoryTitle = $show_category ? '<a href="'.$item->displayCategoryLink.'">'.$item->category_title.'</a>' : '';
        }
        else {
            $item->displayCategoryTitle = $show_category ? $item->category_title : '';
        }

        $item->displayHits = $show_hits ? $item->hits : '';
        $item->displayAuthorName = $show_author ? $item->author : '';
        if ($show_introtext) {
            $item->introtext = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->introtext, '', 'mod_articles_category.content');
            $item->introtext = self::_cleanIntrotext($item->introtext);
        }
        $item->displayIntrotext = $show_introtext ? self::truncate($item->introtext, $introtext_limit) : '';
        $item->displayReadmore = $item->alternative_readmore;

    }

    return $items;
}

public static function _cleanIntrotext($introtext)
{
    $introtext = str_replace('<p>', ' ', $introtext);
    $introtext = str_replace('</p>', ' ', $introtext);
    $introtext = strip_tags($introtext, '<a><em><strong>');

    $introtext = trim($introtext);

    return $introtext;
}

/**
* Method to truncate introtext
*
* The goal is to get the proper length plain text string with as much of
* the html intact as possible with all tags properly closed.
*
* @param string   $html       The content of the introtext to be truncated
* @param integer  $maxLength  The maximum number of charactes to render
*
* @return  string  The truncated string
*/
public static function truncate($html, $maxLength = 0)
{
    $baseLength = strlen($html);
    $diffLength = 0;

    // First get the plain text string. This is the rendered text we want to end up with.
    $ptString = JHtml::_('string.truncate', $html, $maxLength, $noSplit = true, $allowHtml = false);

    for ($maxLength; $maxLength < $baseLength;)
    {
        // Now get the string if we allow html.
        $htmlString = JHtml::_('string.truncate', $html, $maxLength, $noSplit = true, $allowHtml = true);

        // Now get the plain text from the html string.
        $htmlStringToPtString = JHtml::_('string.truncate', $htmlString, $maxLength, $noSplit = true, $allowHtml = false);

        // If the new plain text string matches the original plain text string we are done.
        if ($ptString == $htmlStringToPtString)
        {
            return $htmlString;
        }
        // Get the number of html tag characters in the first $maxlength characters
        $diffLength = strlen($ptString) - strlen($htmlStringToPtString);

        // Set new $maxlength that adjusts for the html tags
        $maxLength += $diffLength;
        if ($baseLength <= $maxLength || $diffLength <= 0)
        {
            return $htmlString;
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

public static function groupBy($list, $fieldName, $article_grouping_direction, $fieldNameToKeep = null)
{
    $grouped = array();

    if (!is_array($list)) {
        if ($list == '') {
            return $grouped;
        }

        $list = array($list);
    }

    foreach($list as $key => $item)
    {
        if (!isset($grouped[$item->$fieldName])) {
            $grouped[$item->$fieldName] = array();
        }

        if (is_null($fieldNameToKeep)) {
            $grouped[$item->$fieldName][$key] = $item;
        }
        else {
            $grouped[$item->$fieldName][$key] = $item->$fieldNameToKeep;
        }

        unset($list[$key]);
    }

    $article_grouping_direction($grouped);

    return $grouped;
}

public static function groupByDate($list, $type = 'year', $article_grouping_direction, $month_year_format = 'F Y')
{
    $grouped = array();

    if (!is_array($list)) {
        if ($list == '') {
            return $grouped;
        }

        $list = array($list);
    }

    foreach($list as $key => $item)
    {
        switch($type)
        {
            case 'month_year':
                $month_year = JString::substr($item->created, 0, 7);

                if (!isset($grouped[$month_year])) {
                    $grouped[$month_year] = array();
                }

                $grouped[$month_year][$key] = $item;
                break;

            case 'year':
            default:
                $year = JString::substr($item->created, 0, 4);

                if (!isset($grouped[$year])) {
                    $grouped[$year] = array();
                }

                $grouped[$year][$key] = $item;
                break;
        }

        unset($list[$key]);
    }

    $article_grouping_direction($grouped);

    if ($type === 'month_year') {
        foreach($grouped as $group => $items)
        {
            $date = new JDate($group);
            $formatted_group = $date->format($month_year_format);
            $grouped[$formatted_group] = $items;
            unset($grouped[$group]);
        }
    }

    return $grouped;
}
```

}

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are trying to do.  Are you saying you want to load the list of articles based on the category of the page you are on? What do you mean by "by the slug not id." First the slug includes the id, and second the request will give you the catid, you can get it from JInput.

Comment: It's a very dynamic, application specific issue I'd say. I just stopped trying to modify the original code and made a query with JDatabase. When I say slug I meant the category alias. For example the breed page is built with the breed alias so I couldn't get the catid so I had to query the DB to get the catid to then pull the articles.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my issue was really specific to the project I am working on. If anyone happens to find this or wants to accomplish something similar, read on.

Decided to accomplish what I was doing using a JDatabase query. To retrieve the articles using the category alias, I queried the DB to match the alias I was giving the query to the category ID. Then joined the content table to get the article information.

All the information you need to make a proper JDatabase query can be found here: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase